# Magento 2.1.3 : How can I add extension attributes to a product attribute?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, extension-attributes

I'm trying to add an extension attribute to a product attribute (`\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute`). I've tried the documentations' examples and various articles on Magento Stack Exchange, but I can't get it to work.

Currently I have the following:

`etc/extension_attributes.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface">
        <attribute code="additions" type="array"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Now if I understand it correctly, this should already return something other than `NULL` when I call `$attribute->getExtensionAttributes()` right? Because currently it doesn't, and I'm clueless to why.

I'm using an event to load additional data and put it into the extension attribute but with no success.

I've also tried applying it directly to the attribute class, rather than the interface, but with no success.

Does anyone has more experience with extension attributes?

Comment: You want to get product `additions` attribute value right?

Comment: No. I want to iterate over alle product attributes and add extra information to it. So it's not `get the attribute of a product`, but rather `get the additions of an attribute of a product`. Additions have no relation to the product, but to the attribute. Is this clear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you mean is adding extension attribute named `Addition` (model) for `Product` model, this may help you.

Create or append `extension_attributes.xml` configuration.

app/code/ProjectName/ModuleName/etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">

    ....

    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
        <attribute code="additions" type="ProjectName\ModuleName\Model\Addition[]"></attribute>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Create `Addition` model.

app/code/ProjectName/ModuleName/Model/Addition.php

```
<?php

namespace ProjectName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Addition extends AbstractModel
{
    ....
}
```

Create `Addition` resource.

app/code/ProjectName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel/Addition.php

```
<?php

namespace ProjectName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Addition extends AbstractDb
{
    ....
}
```

Create `Addition` collection.

app/code/ProjectName/ModuleName/Model/Addition/Collection.php

```
<?php

namespace ProjectName\ModuleName\Model\Addition;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as ProductModel;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    ....

    public function addProductFilter($product)
    {
        if ($product instanceof ProductModel) {
            $product = $product->getId();
        }

        if (is_array($product)) {
            $this->addFieldToFilter('product_id', array('IN' => $product));
        } else {
            $this->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $product);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Create `Product` model plugin configuration.

app/code/ProjectName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    ....

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="projectname_modulename_catalog_product_plugin" type="ProjectName\ModuleName\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create `Product` model plugin class.

app/code/ProjectName/ModuleName/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Product.php

```
<?php

namespace ProjectName\ModuleName\Plugin\Catalog\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as ProductModel;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionFactory;
use ProjectName\ModuleName\Model\Addition\CollectionFactory as AdditionCollectionFactory;

class Product
{
    protected $productExtensionFactory;
    protected $additionCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ProductExtensionFactory $productExtensionFactory,
        AdditionCollectionFactory $additionCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->productExtensionFactory   = $productExtensionFactory;
        $this->additionCollectionFactory = $additionCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function afterLoad(ProductModel $product)
    {
        $productExtension = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
        if (null === $productExtension) {
            $productExtension = $this->productExtensionFactory->create();
        }

        $additionCollection = $this
            ->additionCollectionFactory
            ->create()
            ->addProductFilter($product->getId())
        ;

        $productExtension->setAdditions($additionCollection->getItems());
        $product->setExtensionAttributes($productExtension);

        return $product;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @rendy ko prastiyo is this concept for product Api?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa yes of course, product extension attributes are applicable to product API.

Answer (score 3):

Attribute type cannot be set to "array", it must be one of simple types declared in `\Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor`, or data interface. It can also be an array, but item type should be specific, e.g. `integer[]`.

After fixing that make sure to clear `var/generation` to initiate extension interface regeneration, `\Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeExtensionInterface` should have `getAdditions()` and `setAdditions()` methods generated.

Then you should be able to get/set data to this field from observer or plugin.

Comment: This is a nice simple solution, but in my testing with it, only serialized data will be returned by the API.

```
"customer_tags": [
        "{\"tag_id\":\"7333\",\"tag_name\":\"Great customer\"}"
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

In file `app/code/Namespance/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml` add the attribute.  The `type` is set to a core Magento class.

```
<attribute code="new_attribute_name" type="Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValue[]" />
```

Then elsewhere in the code where the extension data is set, assign an array to this extension attribute.

```
$extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes()
    ? $order->getExtensionAttributes()
    : $this->orderExtensionFactory->create();

$newAttributeNameData = [];
foreach( $sourceData AS $dataItem ) {
  $newAttributeNameData [] = [ 'key_1' => $dataItem ['key_1'], 'key_2' => $dataItem ['key_2'] ];
}

$extensionAttributes->setNewAttributeName( $newAttributeNameData );

$object->setExtensionAttributes( $extensionAttributes );
```