# How to create a custom field for product?

Tags: magento2

I need to make a special text field on a product page which can be filled in by the customer. The value of this field should be passed to the shopping cart and it should be visible in the order.

How can I do this? May be there is a module for this?

Comment: Try This step [Additional Options](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-additional-options-in-magento-2/)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. extension attribute - [Magento 2.1.3 : How can I add extension attributes to a product attribute?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156723/magento-2-1-3-how-can-i-add-extension-attributes-to-a-product-attribute/156939)
2. custom attribute to product - https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-product-attribute-in-magento-2/